# Not able to run psservice.exe and plink.exe from servlet deployed in Tomcat 6.0 using runtime exec and processbuilder

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6, runtime.exec, plink

I am trying to run psservice.exe and plink.exe from servlet using runtime exec. It will be used for starting or stopping services on remote computer running windows and unix aix.

I have set system variables so that i am able to run them from command prompt. These commands are running perfectly from command prompt and java program

I am using below code in Servlets for remote windows machine

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(serverPropLoader.getServerProperties("psservice \\\\172.xx.xx.xx -u username -p password stop MySQL"));
```

I am using below code in Servlets for remote unix aix 5.3 machine

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(serverPropLoader.getServerProperties("PLINK.exe -ssh -pw "password" username@172.xx.xx.xx /home/mysql/stopservice.sh"));
```

Below are my observations :

If i run above statement from Eclipse (ver  3.4.2) using Tomcat6 it runs perfectly fine, but if export my web app as WAR and deploy it in Tomcat6 mannually it dosen't run. ( i have tried deploying it in mine and other system)

I have tried puting these command in Batch file and calling it from servlet but no success. From Batch file "net" and "sc" command are working but i am not able to run pservice and plink command. also "sc" command is working for local processes only.

After execution of servlet i am able to see psservice.exe and plink.exe in windows task manager but required services on local and remote system is not starting / stopping

Comment: I have found a work around for above problem : Now i am creating a new file with name of service to be started \ stopped. I have written a another java program which will read file name and start or stop required service.

Comment: I feel this issue has some thing to do with catalina.policy in tomcat or windows user permission as i able to run Runtime.getRuntime().exec() from normal java program but not from servlet deployed in tomcat. Another strange thing is i am able to run servlet from eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, you need to add admin previladges for the tomcat user.
Because this Apache Tomcat Monitor program requires permission to interact with system services, it cannot be executed as a standard user.

Do following tasks, you will be fine

Locate the tomcat7w.exe program in Windows Explorer (the default directory is C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin).

Right-click the name of this file and select the Properties context menu item.

The tomcat7w Properties dialog displays.
Select the Compatibility tab and click either the "Show settings for all users" button or the "Change settings for all users" button at the bottom of the dialog.

A new tomcat7w.exe Properties dialog displays with a single tab entitled Compatibility for all users.
At the bottom of this dialog, in the Privilege Level group box, select the Run this program as an administrator.

The Apache Tomcat Monitor executable will now execute with the required privileges when run from a standard user account.

for more information pls refer 
https://supportcontent.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Automation%20Point%20Base%2011%204-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/AP--RelNotes/index.htm?toc.htm?2009998.html